# Which is the best way to learn lift if you have no experience on web programming?

Tags: database, scala, frameworks, lift

I'm intending to access DB (postgre) from my applications in scala. I was requested to use lift to do so. Since I have neither experience in web-programming nor in dealing with DB it's not a surprise that I've become really confused with the Lift book.

Could anyone suggest to me another way to begin?

Comment: Are you wanting to use Lift for web application development, or to simply use components of lift to access your database from a scala application?

Comment: Try breaking the learning process into smaller chunks such as how to render HTML views with lift, using Lift's DB library and unit tests to perform some basic CRUD operations, simple buttons that forward between pages, etc. Don't try to tackle learning everything at once.

Comment: @jon I want use lift for web application development but I intend to init with accessing database. @dan The problem is I'm not finding modular references, in addition all the first steps exemples I've found rely on me knowing a lot of things

Comment: Do you have any experience in scala. If not, maybe you should start with learning the basics of scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to learn is to build something with it.

If you need an idea for what to build, check out this exercise wherein someone built the same app with 14 different frameworks: [I am so starving](http://agiliq.com/blog/2010/11/i-am-so-starving-same-web-app-in-various-python-we/). The post only mentions Python, but the author has since added Ruby and JavaScript implementations.